# C# - Visual Studio, how to debug SoapHttpClientProtocol

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to call an external web-service via some proxy code generated by Visual Studio (based on the WSDL from the service). The result object I get back is null, even though I can see that the service does actually return a SOAP message (I can see that in Fiddler).

It appears that the SOAP message is not able to be deserialized by the code generated by Visual Studio. I have read that this can be due to a mismatch between what the service's WSDL tells us what to expect, and what the service actually returns.

Is it possible to get the deserialization code to report what the problem is, throw an exception, or something, instead of just silently returning null?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the debugging, but one approach you can try is to create a simple web service which returns the structure you're expecting. Then you can compare the output from this service with the actual service to see if you see any problems.